# Nativescript css animation stopped working after updating to v3

Tags: css, animation, nativescript

I'm getting the following error when navigating to a page with css animation after upgrading my app to {N} v3

[image]

I'm using the following code:

HTML:

```
  <DockLayout flexDirection="row" class="actionText" backgroundColor="#E1E1E1" stretchLastChild="true" minHeight="65">
                    <Label (tap)="navigate()" dock="left" [text]="'ion-location'| fonticon"  class="ion x-large c-white faa-bounce" textAlignment="center" width="65" style="text-align: center; vertical-align: center;"></Label>
                    <Label [text]="address"  textWrap="true" ></Label>
                </DockLayout>
```

Css:

```
@keyframes bounce {
    0%,10%,20%,50%,80%{transform:translateY(0)}
    40%{transform:translateY(-15px)}
    60%{transform:translateY(-15px)}
}


.faa-bounce {
    animation-name: bounce;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-iteration-count: 3;
    animation-timing-function: ease;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probelm occur for this css animation

```
@keyframes pulse {
    0% {transform: scale(1.1)}
    50% {transform: scale(0.8)}
    100% {transform: scale(1)}
}


.faa-pulse {
    animation-name: pulse;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-iteration-count: 3;
    animation-timing-function: ease;
}
```

I fixed it like below:

```
@keyframes pulse {
    0% {transform: scale(1.1, 1.1)}
    50% {transform: scale(0.8, 0.8)}
    100% {transform: scale(1, 1)}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the breaking changes document:

> Changed method keyframeAnimationFromInfo(info: KeyframeAnimationInfo, valueSourceModifier: number): KeyframeAnimation to KeyframeAnimation.keyframeAnimationFromInfo(info: KeyframeAnimationInfo): KeyframeAnimation. ValueSource no longer needed.

https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/blob/master/Modules30Changes.md

Comment: I don't see what should I modify!